# Assembly.Load fails even assembly is already loaded in domain

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I'm trying to make work the following code (it was decompiled):

```
foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    if ((!assembly.FullName.StartsWith("System") && !assembly.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft")) && !assembly.FullName.StartsWith("mscorlib"))
       {
           list.Add(assembly.FullName);//keep the name of assembly.
       }
}
foreach (string assemblyStirng in list)
{
     var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyString);//here FileNotFoundException is thrown.
}
```

How is it possible? Dll is already in domain and Assembly.Load should return it.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on assembly load logging with fusion log view:
[Fusion Log View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

It will tell you detailed information about why i can't find it.

Some reasons could be, that it was loaded from somewhere else than the application dir, or it did find different versions of the same dll

Comment: FusLog says that the system attemting to find in several locations ([link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx-FqizekZ4aTC12TUFMcW0yZjQ/edit?usp=sharing)). Of course it tries to use correct ways, but DLL was already loaded previously because it contains COM objects.

Comment: i can only see the headline of the document in the link

Comment: but is it actually looking in the right folders where the DLL is located?

Comment: Dlls are located in absolutely different location like D:\Development\bin\blah\blah and of course it cannot find it. But I don't understand why it even tries to do this since the library has been already loaded before and returned by AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that `Assembly.Load(string)` takes an assembly name in it's long form (i.e. strongly named, maybe installed in the GAC), but you're giving it the short assembly name?

Comment: Assembly in NOT installed in the GAC.

Comment: Is it strongly named?

Comment: No, the dll in not strongly named.